Console Ninja is waiting for runtime events. Console ninja does not display inline logging next to my console logs
When I launch my React.js application with Console Ninja active, it displays the message, "Console Ninja is waiting for runtime events. Console Ninja has started with React.js and is now waiting for some runtime logs or errors." However, it doesn't show any log results from my project. The logs do appear in the console when the app is running, which means that the events are being triggered.
Console Ninja has stopped capturing events. There are no logs or trace points available in the console. Moreover, no logs are visible from the backend or the UI.
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the extension, but it still doesn't work.
